# Sir Trevor ordered-list.js Error _ is not defined ordered-list.js:16

Tags: sirtrevor

Just playing with Sir Trevor editor and found some custom blocks that could be used, having some issue with the ordered-list.js, code at **https://github.com/madebymany/sir-trevor-blocks/blob/master/src/ordered-list.js**

I am getting this error message whenever I click on the "Ordered List" icon. 
Error stack:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not definedordered-list.js:16**
Sir Trevor.Blocks.OrderedList.SirTrevor.Block.extend.editorHTMLindex.js:4

Sir Trevor is able to load the ordered list plugin as I can see in the options when I use it, this error happens when I click on the Ordered List icon to use.

Can anyone point me in right direction as to what is going on there, I'm new to javascript and have been struggling with this for a day now.....

Any suggestions?

This is how I load the scripts

```html
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../build/sir-trevor.debug.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../locales/de.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../build/ordered-list.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
      SirTrevor.config.debug = true;
      SirTrevor.config.scribeDebug = true;
      SirTrevor.config.language = "en";

      SirTrevor.setBlockOptions("Text", {
        onBlockRender: function() {
          console.log("Text block rendered");
        }
      });

      window.editor = new SirTrevor.Editor({
        el: $('.sir-trevor'),
        blockTypes: [
            "OrderedList",
          "Heading",
          "Text",
          "List",
          "Quote",
          "Image",
          "Video",
          "Tweet"
        ]
      });

      $('form').bind('submit', function () {
        $('#st-json-debug').text(window.editor.store.toString(true));
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Underscore.js . Thats what the error means. Load that as well.

Comment: Still No Use. Even after adding underscore.js, now the error changed, but still this ordered list dosent work. :(